# How can I create huge terrain for a game

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm making a game and I have a little problem.
I want to make a loop that create new terrains and adds this terrains into list. I don't know how can I do that.

making terrain in main class:

```java
Terrain terrain = new Terrain(0, -1, loader, texturePack, blendMap, "heightmap");

        List<Terrain> terrains = new ArrayList<Terrain>();
        terrains.add(terrain);
```

Terrain constructor:

```java
public Terrain (int gridX, int gridZ, Loader loader, TerrainTexturePack texturePack,
            TerrainTexture blendMap, String heightMap) {


        this.texturePack = texturePack;
        this.blendMap = blendMap;
        this.x = gridX * SIZE;
        this.z = gridZ * SIZE;
        this.model = generateTerrain(loader, heightMap);
        generator = new HeightsGenerator( gridX, gridZ, VERTEX_COUNT, SEED );
        System.out.print("seed of this world : ");
        System.out.println(SEED);

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is. It seems like you should be able to loop and add new `Terrain`s to the list with no problem. What goes wrong when you do?

Comment: when I do that I have a error

Comment: because I don't know how can I change name of new terrain. for example make a for loop and add to name of new terrain  i

Comment: Would you mind editing the question with the `for` loop that you tried? I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: ok thank you for your message